# post parameters in python

Tags: python, authentication, parameters, urllib, httplib

I've tried a lot of codes to post parameters through urllib or httplib.

[image: my parameter]

So, this is my code:

```
import httplib,urllib
para = urllib.urlencode({"username":"test@msn.com","password":"test"})
conn = httplib.HTTPconnection("account.example.com") #consider it's https !
conn.request("POST","/eng/auth/login",para)
res = conn.getresponse()
print res.status , res.reason
```

It's said 301 moved permanently!
Any tips or lead … ?
Thank you even for reading <3

Comment: So when it is https why don't you use HTTPSconnetion?

Comment: Shouldn't `conn.request("POST","/eng/auth/login",para)` be `conn.request("POST","/eng/auth/login",params)`?

Comment: sorry i've wrote wrong variable in the question

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode the parameters:

```
params = urllib.urlencode({"username":"test@msn.com","password":"test"})
```

The 301 might be totally legitimate, your example is posting to a login handler which will typically accept the POST, issue a Cookie and redirect you to the "correct" page to handle your session.

First take a look at the response headers, see if there is a Cookie and what the page is that you are being redirected to.  This should help you figure it out.

Comment: oh dude sorry i forget to write the code with encode .. 
but even with encode it show same response !

Comment: Did you check the location? print res.getheader('location')